# Assemble an Array of Macs to shudown via ssh?

Tags: macos, ssh, shutdown

I want to shutdown a few of my Macs remotely via an ssh script. I've got this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Array of Mac hostnames separated by spaces
my_macs=(mac125 mac122 etc)

#Steps through each hostname and issues SSH command to that host

for n in my_macs
    do
       ssh pcpatch@$n 'sudo bash -s' < ./documents/ShutdownUPTIME.sh
done

exit 0
```

When I run it though, it says:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname my_macs: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: How are the host names being resolved? If it is DNS, then does your machine (the one running the script) have the correct Search Domain settings? If it is Bonjour, then I think you need a '.local' after each host name.

Comment: It is DNS as far as I know. And the machine is a Mac server so it defnitely knows the machine under the name Mac 125 (I only try it right now with one single Mac in the array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through the elements of an array.

```
my_macs=( mac125 mac122 etc )

for n in "${my_macs[@]}"
do
    ssh pcpatch@"${n}" 'sudo bash -s' < ./documents/ShutdownUPTIME.sh
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just overlooked the fact that I had `my_macs` instead of `$my_macs`